# Ng2 Pagination not working

Tags: angular, pagination

I am implementing ng2-pagination from Michael Broomley and it simply does not work.

I did everything I was supposed to do and it does not work.

When I press any of the page numbers, stays on the first page. The page links do not even change to pointer.

video.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of length | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: p }, let i = index">
  <div *ngFor="let video of videos">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 centercontent">
      <h6 id="h6vim">{{video[i].name}}</h6>
      <img id="vimimg" [src]="video[i].pictures.sizes[2].link | safeUrl">
      <a routerLink="/video/{{video[i].resource_key}}">View</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

I need help, please.

Comment: "*It does not work*" is so vague.. Check the [**`PLUNKER`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVQMPvV8z2brCIzdG3N4?p=preview), maybe it points you to the right direction.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I followed that plunker very careful and still does not work. It seems that there are no hyperlink in the pagination list.

Comment: Can you edit the plunker with your data then?

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice to see your component code too, at least for the video structure and the 'videos' property.

Your first iteration loops on a property name length? Looks odd.

Based on the original plunker you would need something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let video of videos | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: p }">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 centercontent">
      <h6 id="h6vim">{{video.name}}</h6>
      <img id="vimimg" [src]="video.pictures.sizes[2].link | safeUrl">
      <a routerLink="'/video/{{video.resource_key}}'">View</a>
  </div>
</div>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```